# Attribute error 'LoginForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data' where login is carried out by mail and password

Tags: python, django

*views.py*

```
def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = form.authenticate_user()
        if not user:
            error(request, 'Wrong credentials!')
            return render_to_response('login.html')
        login(request, user)
        context = user.id
        return start(str(context))
    return render_to_response('login.html', {'form': form})
```

*models.py*

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'
    objects = UserManager()
```

*forms.py*

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False)
    )

    def clean(self):
        user = self.authenticate_via_email()
        if not user:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Sorry, that login was invalid.        Please try again.")
        else:
            self.user = user
        return self.cleaned_data

    def authenticate_user(self):
        return authenticate(
            email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
            password=self.cleaned_data['password']
         )

    def authenticate_via_email(self):
        """
            Authenticate user using email.
            Returns user object if authenticated else None
        """
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if email:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email__iexact=email)
                if user.check_password(self.cleaned_data['password']):
                    return user
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass
        return None
```

why it doesn't work?
Traceback:

```
AttributeError at /auth/
'LoginForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
Traceback:
views.py in login_view
        user = form.authenticate_via_email()

forms.py in authenticate_user
        email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
```

Comment: Fix your indentation, please.

Comment: @vishes_shell Sorry, fixed

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `.is_valid()` on form before accessing `cleaned_data` attribute.

There is not calling `form.is_valid()` in your *views.py*.
Also there is no populating of your form from *POST* data, you need to do it with `form = LoginForm(request.POST)` if your `request.method` is `POST`

You can also view the source:

[`full_clean()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L363-L378) is respected for assigning `self.cleaned_data`, and `full_clean()` is called by property [`self.errors`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L170-L175) in [`is_valid()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L177-L179) method. So you can track from the [django source code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django) what is wrong with yours.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called `form.is_valid()`.
Inorder to access form.cleaned_data, the form validation should be done first.
Form validation is carried out only when `form.is_valid()` is called upon the form, which in turn returns a validated `cleaned_data`.

Also, on `request.POST`, your form is not getting data, because, for that, you need to initialise your form with `request.POST`, like

```
form = LoginForm(request.POST)
```

The return statement before the last `render_to_response` would also raise some errors, I presume.

You could read more about form validation [here from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/)